# Best way to resolve a resource promise in a service

Tags: angularjs

So I have a resource file that is determined by the application language:

```
.constant('defaultLanguage', 'en_EU')

.service('LocalizationService', ['$resource', 'defaultLanguage', function ($resource, language) {

    // Create our service
    var service = {
        get: function () {

            // Use default if no language is supplied
            language = language || 'en_EU';

            // Get the path of the json
            var path = '/assets/resources/' + language + '/resource.json';

            // Return our promise
            var resource = $resource(path).get();

            // Get our promise
            return resource.$promise;
        }
    };

    // Return our service
    return service;
}])
```

What I am trying to do is load the resource file into my application prior to any other service that might be accessing it.
I tried to do this:

```
.run(['LocalizationService', function ($localization) {

    // Get our resource file from the server
    $localization.get().then(function (response) {

        // Assign our response to the service
        $localization.resource = response;

        console.log($localization);
    });
}])
```

with the hope that I could use a service like this:

```
.service('SimpleDesignerValidationService', ['$q', 'LocalizationService', function ($q, localization) {     

    // Create our service
    var service = {

        // Validates the design
        design: function (kit) {

            // Create a deferred promise
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                garments = kit.garments,
                valid = true;

            // For each garment
            for (var i = 0; i < garments.length; i++) {

                // Get our current garment
                var garment = garments[0];

                // if our design is empty
                if (!garment.design) {

                    // We are not valid
                    valid = false;

                    // Break
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If we are not valid
            if (!valid) {

                // Display a warning
                deferred.reject(localization.resource.designInvalid.message);

            // If we are valid
            } else {

                // Resolve our promise
                deferred.resolve();
            }

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    // Return our service
    return service;
}])
```

But the promise has never resolved before I get to my service.
Is there anyway I can make sure a service has resolved it's promises before it is injected into another service or controller?

Comment: Which router are you using?

Comment: If its `ui-router` then you could disabled `ui-router` until `LocalizationService`  resource gets data using `$urlRouter.deferIntercept()`, then again start router to resume router working, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25859767/2435473)

Comment: yours was the answer @PankajParkar. Any chance you can submit an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Sure will do it soon.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can make sure a service has **resolved** it's promises before it is injected into another service or controller

You can use ui.router to [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) the promise before go into another controller. Add your **$localization.get()** in resolve property when you defined state.

Answer (score 0):

You

In a similar situation I ended up to broadcast a message when the translations are loaded. All controllers, that use translations listen to the broadcastet event and do whats necessary to refresh the view.

This is especially usefull, if the user can change the language. In this case you just load another language file and broadcast again.